# How to intercept output to windows 10 cmd.exe and modify to add color?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm invoking another program from the command line to create visual studio solutions and build them. This program outputs the results of those commands.
I want to print warning lines that are output in yellow text rather than the default grey and error lines in red.

Let's assume that my cmd.exe console has already been modified to support rendering ascii2 escape codes to color output.

I've done quite a bit of searching for solutions, but most of the things I've found are made for linux/osx.  I did find a script that given regex as input, could replace text using the specified rules.
[regex script](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044)

Is it possible for me to run this script in the background, but still connected to the cmd.exe, such that it will run on all the text that is output to the cmd.exe, to run the regex search and replace before the text is displayed in the cmd.exe window?  I could put this into a batch file or python script.

I wanted to lay out the specific application, but to make this question potentially more generic, how do I apply an existing script/program to a running cmd.exe prompt in the background, such that the user can still run commands in the cmd prompt, but have the background program apply to the commands run by the user?

I'm open to trying powershell if there are no other performant viable solutions that exist.

The regular expression to detect if a line is an error just searches for the word error

```
"\berror\b"
```

It's the same search for a warning

```
"\bwarning\b"
```

Comment: I/O redirection is not capable of carrying color info, ansi.sys was abandoned a long time ago.  You have stdout and stderr, you can colorize errors pretty easily.

Comment: @HansPassant Does that include ansi escape characters?  Will stderr be in red? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Hard to parse that question.  It is up to you to handle the program's redirected stderr output, what you do with it is entirely up to you.  SetConsoleTextAttribute() is a very basic way.  You are making it harder than necessary by not mentioning a programming language.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the missing pieces.  Typically the user would run the program directly from the command prompt, and the existing script was written in a batch script hybrid with javascript.  I can write an additional batch script to wrap the command execution or python script.

Comment: Yup, be sure to pass the message to the programmer that wrote that redirected program :)

Comment: I am going to try piping the output of python's call to subprocess to stdout to a file, then running the script on that file, then outputting the file contents to the cmd prompt.

Comment: Neither cmd.exe nor powershell.exe is a console or terminal. These are headless shells that can (but not always) attach to a console for their standard I/O. The console is an OS resource that's hosted separately by an instance of conhost.exe (or in threads running in csrss.exe prior to Windows 7). This program of yours that creates Visual Studio solutions either inherits a console from its parent or allocates a new console. That's the extent of the parent's involvement here. If CMD is the parent, its one-and-only thread is just waiting for your program to exit.

Comment: You would have to run an interactive program (IP) that reads stdin and passes that on to a cmd.exe instance that has its stdoutput hooked up to an input stream of the IP that it then processes, adding ANSI escape sequences into the stream as it writes to its own stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Adding the better solution first.  This solution sets up a Pipe so it can receive the output from the external program, then prints the colorized result in realtime.

```
#Python 2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def invoke(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)

    with process.stdout:
        #b'' is byte. Per various other SO posts, we use this method to            
        #iterate to workaround bugs in Python 2
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
            line = line.rstrip()
            if not line:
                continue
            line = line.decode()

            if "error" in line:
                print (bcolors.FAIL + line + bcolors.ENDC)
            elif "warning" in line:
                print (bcolors.WARNING + line + bcolors.ENDC)
            else:
                print (line)

    error_code = process.wait()
    return error_code
```

To accomplish this, I pipped the output of the build command to a file.  I then wrote this python script to install a required dependency, loop through the file contents, then print the data with appropriate coloring.

I will now look into a solution which colors the output in real time, as this solution requires the user to wait for the build to complete before seeing the colored output.

```
#Python 2
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])

class bcolors:
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

def print_text():
    install('colorama')

    try:
        import colorama
        colorama.init()
    except:
        print ("could not import colorama")

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print ("usage: python pretty_print \"file_name\"")
        return 0
    else:
        file_name = sys.argv[1]
        with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as readfile:
            for line in readfile:
                line = line.rstrip()
                if not line:
                    continue

                if "error" in line:
                    print (bcolors.FAIL + line + bcolors.ENDC)
                elif "warning" in line:
                    print (bcolors.WARNING + line + bcolors.ENDC)
                else:
                    print (line)
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ret = print_text()
    sys.exit(ret)
```